# Server pinning one core

Tags: networking, kernel

I'm working on a server using Vert.x in Java and I'm noticing some performance problems when running on a dedicated server running Ubuntu 12.04.

The server picks up the incoming HTTP requests, does some authentication using HMACs, parses the request bodies, does some text processing, and sends data out to a different server over UDP. There's no disk I/O, and only a relatively small amount of memory usage (nowhere close to swap). I'm doing loadtesting against the server using Grinder and AWS instances, but even with a well-geared server I'm unable to get more than 10k requests per second.

What I'm seeing is that one core on the server machine is absolutely pinned, mostly in the kernel, and the other cores are only at ~20-25% utilization. My assumption is that the CPU is being spent on receiving incoming TCP connections. JMX reports most of my time in io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(), which I assume counts time waiting for the kernel, and strace shows a lot of time spent in futex() and epoll_wait().  I've tried playing with kernel settings to increase the throughput of the server, but I haven't had any luck.

Profiler run:

[image: ss of profiler]
*original URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wIZA.png*

CPU usage:

[image: ss of usage]
*original URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mM5u.png*

I'm wondering what can be tuned at the kernel level to help with this.  I've tried messing with TCP buffer sizes, increasing file handles, turning off TCP features, etc., to no avail.  This server OS is actually running on Xen, it's 'dedicated' in that it's the only resident.

Comment: What number is returned in [Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors](http://vertx.io/manual.html#configuring-thread-pool-sizes)?

Comment: You say it is running under XEN - what does `ethtool -i eth0` say about the driver that is being used? Is this a XEN-PV or XEN-HVM? What is the network setup of the Dom0?

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() returns 24.

ethtool says the driver is "vif"

Comment: Working on the other stuff.

Comment: can you spin up a second JVM instance and send 1/2 the load there? does it double the requests/s?

Comment: Maybe try using the multithreaded version of that: http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/nio/NioEventLoopGroup.html

Also, check this out because no one has mentioned it yet:
http://users.sdsc.edu/~glockwood/comp/affinity.php

Sorry, no time ATM to write a full answer.

Comment: I think it's the Vert.x middleware makes use of Netty for it's network heavy lifting and uses the single threaded event loop [NioEventLoop](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/nio/NioEventLoop.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would scrutinize your application and the libraries that it's using. As far as the Linux Kernel is concerned JVM threads are implemented as native threads on Linux (lightweight processes), at least with the Sun/Oracle JVM implementation.

The JVM is a single process with many threads. Each thread that it spins up can run on any of the cores that are available. A single process in Linux can have many threads.

Also you might want to take a look at these resources:

- [Concurrency Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)
- [processes and threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html)
- [Parallel Processing and Multi-Core Utilization with Java](http://embarcaderos.net/2011/01/23/parallel-processing-and-multi-core-utilization-with-java/)
- [How Java multi-threaded program is able to use multiple CPU cores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622373/how-java-multi-threaded-program-is-able-to-use-multiple-cpu-cores)